# Con FormBuilder, no me sale ningún error pero no cargan otros elementos de la vista

Tags: angular

Tengo lo siguiente

.html

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name" pInputText />
<input type="text" formControlName="address.name" pInputText />
<input type="text" formControlName="adress.code" pInputText />
```

.ts

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  workshop: new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]),
    code: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]),
  })
});
```

No me sale ningún error pero no cargan otros elementos de la vista, si elimino los inputs del address me funciona y carga la vista sin problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero tienes una incongruencia en cuanto a los nombres. En el template estas usando `address.name` y `address.code`, pero en el FormGroup de la clase esos controles los tienes dentro de un grupo llamado `workshop`.

Dicho esto, en el template tienes que mantener la estructura definida en el FormGroup de la clase. Este tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
form = {      // FormGroup
  name,         // FormControl
  workshop: {   // FormGroup
    name,         // FormControl
    code          // FormControl
  }
}
```

Por tanto en tu template los debes definir de la siguiente manera (simplificado):

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <fieldset formGroupName="workshop">
    <input formControlName="name">
    <input formControlName="code">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

un saludo

Comment: gracias, el fieldset fue la solución